# Enterprise Architect - showing relations of inner component like it was own

Tags: modeling, enterprise-architect

I have a MyAccount application, that is consists of MyOrders, MyCases, and other MyXXX microservices.

MyOrders communicates with SAP, so on the low level design I specify the relation between MyOrders and SAP.

I would also like to have a high level diagram, where I only show MyAccount box (without all its internals), but still would like to have visible all the external dependencies, so the MyAccount would appear to have relation to SAP.

Question: is it possible to achieve that without the need to maintain 2 relationships explicitly, so that high level diagram is really a derivative on the lower level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, *derived* relations such as that is not supported by Enterprise Architect.

You might be able to write an add-in of some sorts to add support for it yourself though.